# Flask Application Not Dynamically Loading Video Content on Lecture Selection

Tags: flask

I am using Flask to try to develop a website for the first time. I finished the log in system for the website and now I making an online course of sort for those who have logged in. I have set up the log in successfully and now I am trying to make a system where one can watch video lectures. while to the lectures works the actual lectures do not play.

When clicking a lecture the url changes from http://127.0.0.1:5000/course_page/Analytics to http://127.0.0.1:5000/course_page/Analytics#Lecture_2. But the rest of the page does not change does not even open the lecture.

I've set up a Flask route to serve course pages which includes video URLs in the course data. On the frontend, I have a list of lectures that should allow users to click and view the corresponding video. However, the video does not load upon clicking the lecture link.

Here are the essential parts of my code related to this issue:

```
@app.route('/course_page/<course_name>')
def course_page(course_name):
    # Logic to check user session and fetch course data
    # ...
    course_data = get_course_data(course_name)
    return render_template('course_page.html', course=course_data)
```

HTML for Lecture List:

```
<!-- Snippet from course_page.html -->
<div id="sidebar">
    <!-- ... -->
    <ul id="lecture-list">
        {% for lecture in course['lectures'] %}
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="loadVideo('{{ lecture['url']|tojson|safe }}')">
                    {{ lecture['title'] }}
                </a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

JavaScript Function to Load Video:

```
<script>
    // Function intended to load video into the main content area
    function loadVideo(videoUrl) {
        var mainContent = document.getElementById('main-content');
        var fullPath = "{{ url_for('static', filename='') }}" + videoUrl;
        mainContent.innerHTML = '<video controls><source src="' + fullPath + '" type="video/mp4"></video>';
        mainContent.querySelector('video').load();
    }
</script>
```

Despite this setup, when I click a lecture link, the URL changes as expected, but no video appears in the #main-content area. I'm looking for guidance on how to correctly load and display the video content when a lecture link is clicked. Please let me if you need more information.